# retrieve required features of a specific app

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm tring to get all required features of specific app. i wrote this code

```
mPackageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
                mFeatures = mPackageInfo.reqFeatures;
                if(mFeatures != null) {
                for(FeatureInfo feature : mFeatures) {
                    mString.append(feature.name);
                }
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("test", "error");
                }
```

mFeatures is FeatureInfo[] variable. mString is StringBuffer type variable. in my logcat i see error. why? how can i solve?

Comment: post logcat output..]

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: i try also to put a log and mFeatures is null but the variable packageName is correct

Comment: could you post your logcat error?it will helps other in tracking problem

Comment: the packageName is correct. in logcat i see error and also mFeatures is NULL! why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `0` in your `getPackageInfo()` call [with `PackageManager.GET_CONFIGURATIONS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#GET_CONFIGURATIONS).